# how to get data from razorpay webhook

Tags: asp.net, webhooks, razorpay

I enabled the webhook url in razorpay

[image: Webhook]

But I didn't understand how to get the data from webhook url when the payment is failed.

Give the best example to understand this concept

[and is it possible to get the data using postman also?]

I'm fresher in aspdot.net coding.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up the webhook in razorpay to send failed payment event.
Click Edit on webhook details check the checkbox "payment.failed"

The webhook request will send 'event' with data 'payment.failed'

Answer (score 0):

Using Razorpay webhooks merchants can set up triggers to call their BE when an event like payment is failed, payment is captured, etc. happens.

On Razorpay Merchant [dashboard](https://dashboard.razorpay.com) webhooks can be set up by navigating to `Settings > Webhooks`. Here is detailed documentation for [setting up Razorpay webhooks using dashboard](https://razorpay.com/docs/webhooks/setup-edit-payments) & [payload reference](https://razorpay.com/docs/webhooks/payloads/payments#payment-failed) for the payment-failed event